# Cross browser testing with Selenium-Cucumber Maven framework

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, jvm, cucumber-junit

I am using selenium cucumber maven framework with Junit. I need to run the tests in multiple browsers. How can i achieve this? Can anyone help me? my TestRunnerTest.java file is as below:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/1login.feature"
        , glue= {"stepDefinition"}
, plugin = { "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, 
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestRunnerTest {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static String timeStamp = new 
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
private static TestRunnerTest sharedInstance = new TestRunnerTest();
private TestRunnerTest() { }

public static TestRunnerTest getInstance() {
    return sharedInstance;
}

@BeforeClass
public static void before() {   

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\ChromeDriverNew\\chromedriver.exe");
       driver=new ChromeDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 }
@AfterClass
public static void after() {


 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
          public void run()
          {         
            try {
                 Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
                Files.move(Paths.get("target/cucumber-reports"), Paths.get("target/cucumber-reports_ "+ 
            LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("L-d-YYYY H-m-s"))), 
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });

driver.quit();
}
```

And my baseDefinition is as below:

```
public class baseDefinition {
public Boolean beforsuit=true;
public String baseurl = "https://click2rail-dev.cloudiumedge.com";
private static TestRunnerTest runner_TestObj = TestRunnerTest.getInstance();
public  WebDriver driver = runner_TestObj.driver;   
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new 
Date());
}
```

Now I need to run the test in multiple browsers (Chrome,Firefox,IE). What are the changes i need to do in the TestRunner.java file & baseDefinition file ? It would be very helpful if you guys help me with a solution since I am a beginner. I have searched so many times ..But i am getting the solutions with TestNG .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach of doing this would be to have an environment variable for browser name. Since you are using maven, you can simply inject the browser name environment variable while initiating the test from command line. Example: `mvn test -DbrowserName=Firefox`

You may then modify your @BeforeClass method to have a conditional check based on the browser name.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void before() {   

       String browserName=System.getenv("browserName");
    if (browserName
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\ChromeDriverNew\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
    } else if (browserName
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
        //Set gecko driver path and initiate firefox 
    } else if (browserName
            .equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
        //Set IEDriver path and initiate IE
    } else {
        logger.debug("Error Message----> "
                + "browser name not mentioned properly");
        System.exit(0);
    }
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bounty . After editing the @BeforeClass as you mentioned, getting null pointer exceptions at these lines .       driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.quit() . could you please help me to solve this

Comment: It seems you are not passing the env variable. Could you try replacing `String browserName=System.getenv("browserName");` with `String browserName="Firefox";`. Please mark the answer as accepted if this helps

Comment: I have replaced and still getting this null pointer exception. And when I tried to print the browser name that i am trying to pass through command line , it is printing the text 'null' . Please help Bounty

Comment: Does it work fine when you write `String browserName="Firefox";`?

Comment: wrote like this- String browserName=System.getenv("Firefox"); since i need to pass the browser name through CLI . But it doesn't worked

Comment: Writing `String browserName=System.getenv("Firefox");` means you are looking for an environment variable with name Firefox which I believe is not being set. I would recommend you set an environment variable explicitly. Use the following link for details on how to set environment variable: https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842

Comment: Yes Bounty ...   when I wrote String browserName="Firefox"; and run mvn test -DbrowserName=firefox from CLI,  this worked for me.. so now my doubt is do we need to mention the browserName in the TestRunner file and also in the CLI ??

Comment: Is you specify `String browserName="Firefox";`, you only need to run `mvn test` (-DbrowserName=firefox is redundant and can be omitted). So when running through CLI, simply run `mvn test`  and specify the required browser in your test code

Comment: Thanks Bounty. But what actually i need is to run the test from CLI by passing the browser name along with the command from CLI.
Can we able to handle this by using the environment variable .

Comment: As mentioned earlier, the line `String browserName=System.getenv("Firefox");` looks for an environment variable with name Firefox. Use the link I shared in one of my previous comments to set environment variable titled Firefox explicitly and then run your script without hard-coding the browserName variable

Comment: Bounty, I have updated the TestRunner code with  browserName = System.getProperty("browserName"); and it worked for me.. Thank you so much for your help throughout these days.

Comment: Hi @BountyHunter, I tried this approach and it's only possible with one browserName. If I add more than one browserName, then the test is only run in one. Is it possible to run the same test with multiple browsers?